# My Powerstrip color profile disappears?

Tags: windows-7, powerstrip

I use Powerstrip to calibrate my new flat screen and I've added my new color profile to the existing color profiles. My problem is when I reboot my rig Powerstrip informs me about an incomplete program shutdown and my color profile disappears? When I open the color preferences menu I can see only the default profiles and not my deleted color profile? I'm using the evaluation version. How can I fix this problem with the incomplete shutdown and most important how can I rescue my lost color profile?

Comment: Have you done Profile Save as, and verified that it was saved where it is supposed to?

Comment: @harrymc: I want to share my profile but I can't find it. I've looked in the installation folder and the document folder and the registry but I can't find the information of the where.

Comment: Did you try searching by file-name ?

Comment: @harrymc: Do you mean profile name? There isn't a file name. Can I use the Windows search function? I've disabled the windows index service?

Comment: The free [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) is better than Windows search.

Comment: Windows search didn't found anything. I check process.exe to monitor the application. Will see what I find?

Comment: @harrymc: I can't find it. Not with process monitor or windows search or Agent Ransack? Where can it store the name and the information?

Comment: Well, the other possibility is that it is stored on the monitor itself using its firmware. This means that this monitor is not fully supported by Powerstrip. You could raise the question in the [Powerstrip forums](http://www.entechtaiwan.net/forums/).

Comment: @harrymc: I don't understand. I don't understand why I can't monitor with process.exe. Maybe it's this file: http://forums.entechtaiwan.com/index.php?topic=138.0?

Comment: Seems like, have you found it?

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, many thanks. It was in /user/username/appdata/roaming. It's a text file with my profile names. It also contains serial number of the monitor.

Comment: Well, you had better then write up an answer to your post.

Comment: @harrymc: Ok. I' will write an anwser. I didn't check if it's the whole color profile. Currently I see only my names.

Comment: Then you haven't found it all. If you post the file I could have a look at it.

Comment: Is that after doing the modification? If not, please also post this same file after adding and saving your resolutions (before rebooting). In any case, at first look this file seems to be quite complete with all the required information per resolution.

Comment: You can see in color profile tree my saved profiles, e.g. acer, acer 2, acer backup. But I can't see any other bits?

Comment: I believe that the part `[acer 2]
HW.95521002.21ED1458.0200=-16,-3,-3,-1,10,10,49,44,44,15,0,0` completely defines your profile. I just don't have any idea about the meaning of these numbers.

Comment: My Pastebin of a diff http://pastebin.com/GEU3dVyn. IMO this line is to few bits to decode RGB+Gamma curce. In the diff you can see more changes to the file. It's seems to be very special format.

Comment: Some of these values are probably pointers to other sections in the file, so the number of bits is not conclusive.